# rolling apply for a binary (or n-ary) function in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I wanted to take a pandas DataFrame that has two columns and calculate rolling covariance between two of the columns.  The catch is that sometimes I want to assume the mean is zero and sometimes I will want the proper sample covariance that is demeaned.

To do this, I have the following function that I would like to use a rolling apply with - all this does is calculate covariance assuming zero mean if not centered and calculate the usual covariance when it is centered.

```
def real_cov(x,y, centered=True):
    return (((x-(x.mean() if centered else 0))*(y-(y.mean() if centered else 0))).sum()/(len(x)-1))

# Make this a binary function
real_cov_uncentered = lambda x,y: real_cov(x,y,False)
```

now assume that df is a DataFrame with 2 columns and 100 rows of numbers.

I would like to use a pandas rolling_apply function to calculate the uncentered rolling covariance using my custom function, real_cov_uncentered.

i.e. I want this code to work:

```
rolling_cov=pd.rolling_apply(df, window=20, func=real_cov_uncentered)
```

This does not work because I obviously cannot convince pandas to treat the two columns in df as the two arguments to real_cov_uncentered.

Any suggestions?  Let me know if I am not being clear and I will edit.

On Edit 1:
I should add that my attempts at some hackish cleverness (that would have been unsatisfying even if it worked) also failed:

```
def zipped_cov(two_tuple, centered=True):
    x=np.array([two_tuple[i][0] for i in np.arange(len(two_tuple))])
    y=np.array([two_tuple[i][1] for i in np.arange(len(two_tuple))])
    return real_cov(x,y,centered)

zipped_df=pd.Series(data=zip(df['col1'], df['col2']), index=df.index)
rolling_cov=pd.rolling_apply(zipped_df, window=20, func=lambda x: zipped_cov(x, False))
```

Here, what I was doing was forcing my covariance call to be a unary function by zipping my two columns into one column, and then calling the zipped_cov function, which would unzip and call the original covariance function.  It seems that under the hood, pandas would rather vomit than do this for me:

Error Msg:

```
C:\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\stats\moments.pyc in _process_data_structure(arg, kill_inf)
    330 
    331     if not issubclass(values.dtype.type, float):
--> 332         values = values.astype(float)
    333 
    334     if kill_inf:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```